# android - AutoCompleteTextView dropDown height is not correct

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I use custom view in dropDown item.
I have two items: the first item contains one line, the second item contains two lines. But dropDown height is equal two line, instead of three and adds scrollView (see screenshot).
Similarly, if I have three items, which have a different number of lines, dropDown height is equal three line.

[image]

[image]

How to set height of dropdown correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setDropDownHeight()` method of `AutoCompleteTextView` e.g :

```
int sumHeight = textVeiw1.getHeight()+textView2.getHeight();
autoEditText.setDropDownHeight(sumHeight);
```